How to use restored key to decode an encoded column in SQL Server?
In SQL server, I created a symmetric key and encoded a column as per An overview of the column level SQL Server encryption
use AdventureWorks2022
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'SQLShack@1';
CREATE CERTIFICATE Certificate_test WITH SUBJECT = 'Protect my data';
CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY SymKey_test WITH ALGORITHM = AES_256 ENCRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Certificate_test;

-- encode using symmetric keys
ALTER TABLE AdventureWorks2022.HumanResources.Employee
        ADD BankACCNumber_encrypt varbinary(MAX)
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SymKey_test
        DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Certificate_test;
UPDATE AdventureWorks2022.HumanResources.Employee
        SET BankACCNumber_encrypt = EncryptByKey (Key_GUID('SymKey_test'), NationalIDNumber)
        FROM AdventureWorks2022.HumanResources.Employee;
CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY SymKey_test;
select BankACCNumber_encrypt,* from AdventureWorks2022.HumanResources.Employee

I decode succeessfully with:
-- decode
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SymKey_test
        DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Certificate_test;
SELECT nationalIDNumber,BankACCNumber_encrypt AS 'Encrypted data',
            CONVERT(nvarchar, DecryptByKey(BankACCNumber_encrypt)) AS 'Decrypted Bank account number'
            FROM AdventureWorks2022.HumanResources.Employee

I backed up the symmetric key, pretended it was lost/dropped, and restored the key using:
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SymKey_test
        DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Certificate_test
BACKUP SYMMETRIC KEY SymKey_test  
    TO FILE = 'C:\stuff\Sym_key_backup.cer'
    ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'A4FR^hhjg££fhj'
CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY SymKey_test;  
DROP SYMMETRIC KEY SymKey_test;
RESTORE SYMMETRIC KEY key_name FROM 
    FILE = 'C:\stuff\Sym_key_backup.cer'
      DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'A4FR^hhjg££fhj' 
      ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '3dH85Hhk003GHk2597gheij4' 

I then try to decode, using:
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY key_name
        DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Certificate_test;
SELECT nationalIDNumber,BankACCNumber_encrypt AS 'Encrypted data',
            CONVERT(nvarchar, DecryptByKey(BankACCNumber_encrypt)) AS 'Decrypted Bank account number'
            FROM AdventureWorks2022.HumanResources.Employee

but it does not decrypt correctly, and I get error:

The key is not encrypted using the specified decryptor.

How can I use the restored symmetric key to decode my encoded column?

When you first created the SYMMETRIC KEY you used the option ENCRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Certificate_test and the key was encrypted using a certificate, but the RESTORE SYMMETRIC KEY command does not have that same option (strange limitation) and you had to use the ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '3dH85Hhk003GHk2597gheij4' as follows:
RESTORE SYMMETRIC KEY key_name FROM 
    FILE = 'C:\stuff\Sym_key_backup.cer'
      DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'A4FR^hhjg££fhj' 
      ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '3dH85Hhk003GHk2597gheij4'

It means now you have to open the symmetric key using that password you defined during the restoration:
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY key_name
        DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '3dH85Hhk003GHk2597gheij4'


Notice
The lack of an option to restore the key using ENCRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE seems to weaken the security of the key according to this warning on the doc:

Caution
When a symmetric key is encrypted with a password instead of a
certificate (or another key), the TRIPLE DES encryption algorithm is
used to encrypt the password. Because of this, keys that are created
with a strong encryption algorithm, such as AES, are themselves
secured by a weaker algorithm.

I believe an option to that would be Create identical symmetric keys on two servers
Another option is to alter it after restoring it:
ALTER SYMMETRIC KEY key_name ADD ENCRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Certificate_test;
ALTER SYMMETRIC KEY key_name DROP ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '3dH85Hhk003GHk2597gheij4';


as per your link: But when encryption and decryption occur in separate databases or on separate servers, the key stored in one database isn't available for use on the second database.

Glad to assist =). About that excerpt, it's only stating that if you're gonna decrypt data on the same database, you have do to nothing since the key exists there. But if you're gonna decrypt data on a second server or database, you need to have a copy of that key. Thus the documentation to create (or recreate) an identical key.
